# How to get data from a client on load?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, io, webbrowser-control

I'm aware that data can be passed in through the URL, like "example.com/thing?id=1234", or it can be passed in through a form and a "submit" button, but neither of these methods will work for me.

I need to get a fairly large xml string/file. I need to parse it and get the data from it before I can even display my page.

How can I get this on page load? Does the client have to send a http request? Or submit the xml as a string to a hidden form?

---

Edit with background info:

I am creating a widget that will appear in my customer's application, embedded using C# WebBrowser control, but will be hosted on my server. The web app needs to pass some data (including a token for client validation) to my widget via xml, and this needs to be loaded in first thing when my widget starts up.

Comment: You'll need to provide a way for them to provide you with the xml file. Most common way is to have an simple page with only an upload file input and then only after the file is processed will you display the regular page.

Comment: @Queti, I can't create an additional page or field for this; this needs to happen *on load*, because I don't get the xml directly from the user. It's generated by another page which is calling my page, all happening in the background...

Comment: So are the users involved in uploading the xml file or is it done by some process that doesn't involve the user direct input?

Comment: It doesn't involve user input.

Comment: I added some more information to the question about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How is the widget being embedded? JS/iFrame/server control, etc??

Comment: Automatic uploading a file via Ajax is and will never work for a good reason, as any malicious page could grab files on the client side.

Comment: The widget is being embedded using C# WebBrowser control

Comment: Perhaps walk us through the program flow.  You say the XML is created by anohter page and then consumed finally by your widget to display the necessary data.  What prompts the creation of the XML?  Does all of this happen as a redirect such that a request is made to one page (perhaps with authentication information) which then prompts the generation of the XML and then redirection to the ultimate page which will use the XML data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 4 works great with jQuery and aJax posts.  I have accomplished this goal many times by taking advantage of this.

**jQuery:**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/{controller}/{action}/",
                data: { clientToken: '{token}', foo: 'bar',
                success: function (data, text) {
                        //APPEND YOUR PAGE WITH YOUR PARSED XML DATA
                        //NOTE: 'data' WILL CONTAIN YOUR RETURNED RESULT
                }
            });
        });
```

**MVC Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult jqGetXML(string clientToken, string foo)
    {
        JsonResult jqResult = new JsonResult();

        //GET YOUR XML DATA AND DO YOUR WORK
        jqResult.Data = //WHATEVER YOU WANT TO RETURN;

        return jqResult;
    }
```

**Note:**  This example returns Json data (*easier to work with IMO*), not XML.  It also assumes that the XML data is not coming from the client but is stored server-side.

**EDIT:** Here is a link to jQuery's Ajax documentation,
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ASP.NET, since you say it's generated by another page, just stick the  XML in the `Session` state.

Comment: Yeah, this *works*, but if it's of any real size like the OP suggests it's a very poor use of resources server-side and potentially risks performance and stability.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, not sure if it helps in your situation.

If you share the second level domain name on your two sites (i.e. .....sitename.com ) then another potential way to share data is you could have them assert a cookie at this 2nd level with the token and xml data in it.  You'll then be provided with this cookie.

I've only done this to share authentication details, you need to share machine keys at a minimum to support this (assuming .Net here...).

Answer (score 0):

Sample solution:

Background process imports xml file and parses it. The background process knows it is for customer YYY and updates their information so it know the xml file has been processed.

A visitor goes to the customer's web application where the widget is embedded. In the markup of the widget the customer token has been added. This could be in JavaScript, Flash, iFrame, etc.

When the widget loads, it makes a request to you app which then checks to see if the file was parsed for the provided customer (YYY) if it has, then show the page/widget.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to automatically upload a file from the client to the server - at least not via a browser using html/js/httprequests.  The browser simply will not allow this.

Imagine the security implications if browsers allowed you to silently upload a file from the clients local machine without their knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is being served via HTTP you can use Liqn to parse the data.

Ex.

```
 public partial class Sample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://news.yahoo.com/rss/";
        var el = XElement.Load(url).Elements("channel");

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var c in el.Elements())
        {
            switch (c.Name.LocalName.ToLower())
            {
                case "title": 
                    output.Append(c.Value);
                    output.Append("<br />");
                    break;
            }
        }

        this.Label1.Text = output.ToString();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what the application is and what kind of options you have, and what kind of control over web server you have.

If you are the owner of the web server/application your options are way wider. You can first send a file to web-server with HTTP POST or PUT, including a random token, and then use the same token for GET with token in the query string

or use other options, applicable to third party-owned websites

if you are trying to consume some auth api, learn more about it. since you are hosting web browser control, you have plenty of options to script it. including loading whatever form, setting textarea or hidden field text with your xml and then simulating a submit button click. you can then respond to any redirects and html responses.

you can also inject javascript inside the page that would send it to server with ajax request.

the choice heavily depends on the interaction model.

if you need better advice, it would be most helpful if you provided sample/simplified url/url pattern, form content, and sequence of events that is expected from you from code/api/sdk perspective. they are usually quite friendly.

Answer (score 0):

There are limited number of ways to pass data between pages. Personally for this I would keep in session during the generating page and clear it when it is retrieved in the required page.
If it is generated server side then there is no reason to retrieve it from client side.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a webservice that your C# app can POST the XML to and get back HTML in response.  Load this HTML string into the WebBrowser control rather than pointing the control to a URL.